# React useState cant be found in a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

using functional components to build out my ui. My register component cant find the `import react, {useState} from 'react'` It gives me back this error.

```
Failed to compile.

./src/pages/Register.js
  Line 10:31:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "register"
 which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function 
 react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error
```

My App Structure is [image]

I have deleted react and reinstalled it with no luck

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";

function register() {
  const initialState = {
    username: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
    email: "",
  };
  const [values, setvalues] = useState(initialState);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>register</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default register;
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: Can u share your code in Register.js with us?

Comment: It's probably because of the way you name your component. It should be Register and not register. React component name should start with a Capital, with same convention of how you normally name a class

Comment: just did @AlejandroLariccia

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that components names must be capitalized in react. must be "Register" and no "register".